# What does the grey arrow on the minimap mean?

Tags: the-witcher-2

[image: minimap]

What does the grey arrow on the right side mean? Is it somehow related to that sun inside of circle thing?

Comment: Is it not simply a pointer to North?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just checked the 3.2 patch notes where this was added. It's the north pointer.